# About Causative form

Tags: causative-have

Are the following sentences in Causative form and grammatically correct?

> I want you to have my car cleaned.
>
> I'd like to have you clean my car.

Answer (score 8):

They're fine sentences, but they mean different things.

The first means that I want you to find somebody else to clean my car.

The second means I have selected you to clean my car.